# script to automate exporting confluence spaces to html

Tags: bash, confluence

So, here's the problem I'm having. I need to export all of the spaces on my company's confluence page to HTML on a regular basis. I'm currently looking at using bash's curl and wget commands to get what I'm looking for.

What I'm trying to do:

-Log onto confluence using username:password....(DONE using: 
curl username:password url)

-Export the space to html, wait the 15-30 seconds to generate the link to download the zip file...(not done)

-Unzip to chosen directory and remove zip file (DONE using unzip command)

The company I work for won't let me download modules for bash nor add-ons to confluence that would make my life easier. Am I barking up the wrong tree with BASH altogether? The research I've been doing on this has turned up very little.

tl;dr: I need a bash command that will (1) log on to a URL, (2) Click a button to navigate to the next page, (3) Wait for said page to generate the link and (4) Click that link to download the file.

Comment: http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: https://developer.atlassian.com/confcloud/confluence-rest-api-39985291.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a POST request using curl to:

http://confluence-domain.com/confluence/spaces/doexportspace.action?key={space-key}

Add the type=TYPE_HTML as data

You can narrow down the content you want exported using the contentToBeExported fields and so on.

A simple google search led me to this script, which has most of what you want already: 
https://gist.github.com/Lixivial/320948

Answer (score 0):

One can use this Python 2 script to export Confluence spaces and pages recursively via its API: https://github.com/siemens/confluence-dumper ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/confluence-dumper)).

One can select the space(s) to export in `settings.py`:
https://github.com/siemens/confluence-dumper/blob/2843a9e577f5a918723929edb420670d73568905/settings.sample.py#L17